# JSON and Teradata

Tags: sql, json, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have the following JSON:

```
'{"0": false,"1": false,"barring": "BAR_ROAMING"}'
```

There is a propriety in teradata for Json that can be used to extract barring value `F_JSON.barring` --> `BAR_ROAMING`

But for the other 2, which are dynamic keys, how can I extract them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using

```
CREATE TABLE KEY_JSON AS (
SELECT DISTINCT(JSONKeys) J_KEY FROM Json_Keys
    (
    ON (SELECT JSON FROM JSON_TABLE) USING QUOTES('N'))
    AS json_data) WITH DATA;
```

And performing a `JOIN` between my 2 tables `(JSON_TABLE and KEY_JSON) ON JSON LIKE '%||J_KEY||%'`

And extracting the value using `JSONEXTRACT(JSON.'$."||J_KEY)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSONExtractValue function:

```
select JsonCol.JSONExtractValue('$.[0]') as FirstOne
     , JsonCol.JSONExtractValue('$.[1]') as SecondOne
from (
   select new json('{"0": false,"1": false,"barring": "BAR_ROAMING"}')
    ) MyJsonData(JsonCol)
```

https://docs.teradata.com/r/HN9cf0JB0JlWCXaQm6KDvw/aaGwlJOTKsXk4IaU7vsE6g

Comment: If 0 and 1 were not dynamic, I agree with you. But they are dynamic and can change.